# SSRS Count Occurances based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, count

I have a dataset which returns data in the following format;

### StartDate | EndDate | Resource | WBS

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | EFGH

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Jane Doe | ABCD

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Joe Blogs | IJKL

yyyy-mm-08 | yyyy-mm-14 | John Doe | ABCD

etc

How can I count the occurrences of the startdate, enddate and resource only (not the wbs), and have that count display on each row - so that i can use the count to calculate the allocation per wbs, per week.

e.g. in the above example, the output should be;

### StartDate | EndDate | Resource | WBS | Allocation

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD | 50%

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | EFGH | 50%

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Jane Doe | ABCD | 100%

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Joe Blogs | IJKL | 100%

yyyy-mm-08 | yyyy-mm-14 | John Doe | ABCD | 100%

etc

Thanks in advance for any help - please let me know if i've been unclear in anyway.

Sidenote - I've tried adding row groups, and can get the correct count - however this does not put the count on each row, instead it does the following (not sure how clear that one is);

### StartDate | EndDate | Resource | WBS | Allocation

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD || 25%

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | EFGH ||

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Jane Doe | ABCD || 100%

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | Joe Blogs | IJKL || 100%

yyyy-mm-08 | yyyy-mm-14 | John Doe | ABCD || 100%

etc

EDIT:
The proposed solution by @Hannover Fist seemed to be working, but I'm getting some unexpected behaviour from the lookupset.

The last row is being overwritten with the second-to-last row.
when the lookupset is set as Fields!StartDate.Value & "|" & Fields!EndDate.Value, all columns show the correct values (except the allocation).
But if i add in the & "|" & Fields!Resource.Value;

I the second-to-last row repeated.
i.e.

### StartDate | EndDate | Resource | WBS

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD

While my dataset actually has 2 rows;

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | ABCD

yyyy-mm-01 | yyyy-mm-07 | John Doe | EFGH

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I actually have no idea whats happening with it..
At first i thought it could be a conversion error or something - but that doesn't make sense seeming it doesnt repeat the row when just the start and end date are shown (they would need to be converted to a string because of the & "|").
Even still - i tried putting the start and end dates in a CSTR().
Still repeating though.

Comment: I don't understand the result of sample data. As your mention, 3 rows first have same data of Start, End and Resource. I think result like: 33%, 33%, 33% (~1/3). Why expect result: 50%, 50%, 100%?

Comment: He expects the result add the two "50%" values relate to John Doe, and the "100%" value relates to Jane Doe

Comment: Are you able to edit the underlying SQL which gives you this dataset? To use to calculate more columns which will help perhaps?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều As Jonnus mentioned - they are two different resources. Sorry - I should have used names that were a bit more distinct.

Comment: @Jonnus Yes, I am able to edit the underlying SQL, but would prefer not to, as the query is already quite complicated (uses recursion, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the **SumLookup** function to get the overall total of each group and divide your count by the total.

**Allocation** expression:

```
=COUTROWS() / Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(
 Fields!StartDate.Value & "|" & Fields!EndDate.Value & "|" & Fields!Resource.Value, 
 Fields!StartDate.Value & "|" & Fields!EndDate.Value & "|" & Fields!Resource.Value, 
 1, "Dataset1"))
```

Code:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal

If items Is Nothing Then
  Return Nothing
End If

Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0

For Each item As Object In items
  suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  ct += 1
Next

If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

[Summing lookups in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676808/summing-lookups-in-ssrs)

http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/

Comment: This works correctly. Thanks heaps!
With slight altercation anyhow - You forgot the End If for the last if.
Also - whats the purpose of the countrows, as opposed to just 1?
Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: At first glance it seemed to be working - however theres some unexpected behaviour coming from the lookupset. Please see the edit to the original question.

Comment: The Lookup should only be affecting the one column for the % calculation. Are you grouping your rows on Start Date, End Date, Resource **and** WBS?

Comment: I agree - it SHOULDN'T affect any other column - but for some reason it is :\
I added a brand new table - so there isn't any grouping on it at the moment.
I just tried altering the rowgroup to group by StartDate, EndDate, Resource and WBS - it makes no difference.