# SSRS mutiple database source to be joined

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, reporting-services

Just stuck on getting information from two sources, we have a MYSQL database for repairs information which I have in SSRS, this brings back 7000 rows. We have another Repairs database in Oracle which brings back over 3 million rows.

I can't seem to bring the one from oracle as it exceeds the maximum limit, but is there any way do a left join using so i can bring only the two columns i need from the oracle one into the MySQl one which would mean i have 7000 rows plus the 2 columns from Oracle which have a common Primary key. I can't seem to join on two dataset with it being on two database.

Can anyone help.

THank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Lookup** function in SSRS to find a value from one dataset based on a common key.

```
=Lookup(Fields!SaleProdId.Value, Fields!ProductID.Value,  Fields!Name.Value, "Product")
```

> Use Lookup to retrieve the value from the specified dataset for a
>   name-value pair where there is a 1-to-1 relationship. For example, for
>   an ID field in a table, you can use Lookup to retrieve the
>   corresponding Name field from a dataset that is not bound to the data
>   region.
>   (BIDs Description)

In the above example, the **SalesProdID** from one dataset is being used to relate to the **ProductID** in the **Product** table to get the **Name** field.

This will only return one value, though. This may or may not be OK depending on your data. If you need to return multiple values, use **LookupSet**.

```
=LookupSet(Fields!TerritoryGroupID.Value, Fields!TerritoryID.Value, Fields!StoreName.value, "Stores")
```

> Use LookupSet to retrieve a set of values from the specified dataset
>   for a name-value pair where there is a 1-to-many relationship. For
>   example, for a customer identifier in a table, you can use LookupSet
>   to retrieve all the associated phone numbers for that customer from a
>   dataset that is not bound to the data region.

Unfortunately, you might need to SUM a Lookup but that isn't supported by a function in SSRS. Fortunately, users created a function for it:

[SSRS Count Occurances based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357355/ssrs-count-occurances-based-on-multiple-columns/33380204#33380204)